# MInecraft Adventure mode protection within a survival mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am setting protection in factions on my command block server using adventure mode. I have a command block setting mode to survival in a certain radius, but within that radius I want a smaller radius set to adventure mode. Is there a way to set what's not in the radius of adventure mode to survival mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entity selector has several arguments I think you'll find useful for this kind of situation. r=6 (as you probably know) targets entities within a spherical radius of 6. rm can be used to specify a minimum radius. and dx dy dz can be used for a rectangular region. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands has a nice list and explination of all valid selector arguments.

For your problem, I would use something like `/gamemode 2 @a[r=10,m=0] followed by /gamemode 0 @a[r=5,m=2]`   but there are many ways to do this with the available selectors

Comment: what do you mean by a minimum radius?

Comment: A minimum radius only targets entities outside the range specified. For example, rm=3 would find entities 3 or more blocks away (sphericaly), but not any closer. I'm combination with a normal radius, you can create a ring or band of space to target.

Answer (score 0):

**Try making 5 different radiuses.** *Place the Survival radius in the center, and the other 4 around it, with eventual overlaping.*
***Warning: This method might leave a few blocks out of any radius.***